# How to do this in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, string-aggregation

```
Table: A                  Table: B                 Table: C
------------            ----------------          -------------
P_id | G_id              P_id  |  Name            G_id | Title
------------            ----------------          -------------
 1   |  1                 1    | john              1   | php
 2   |  1                 2    | jack              2   | sql
 3   |  2                 3    | sam
```

Now I am quering like:

```
Select B.name, C.title
from B inner join A on...
inner join c on...
```

If we input john here then it will display like this:

```
john php.
```

But I want to display it like:

```
john jack  php.
```

Because G_id of john and jack is same.
How can i do this?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Do you mean output `john` `jack` and `php` on separate rows or as literally `john jack php`?

Comment: do you want John and Jack in separate columns?

Comment: I think he wants a pivot, but I want to see which db before I answer

Comment: John and jack in same column...  php in separate column

Comment: Would you please choose an Answer to Accept?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code (similar to mysql):

```
SELECT B.name, C.title 
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.P_id = B.P_id
INNER JOIN C ON A.G_id = C.G_id
WHERE A.G_id = (
                 SELECT A.G_id 
                 FROM B
                 INNER JOIN A ON A.P_id = B.P_id
                 WHERE B.Name LIKE '%John%' LIMIT 1
               );
```

**EDIT:**

This will make your results searchable by name, use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and GROUP BY as suggested by **Everton Agner** to correctly format the results.

Comment: +1, it works okay... just add the group_concat and he's good to go

Answer (score 1):

You need an Aggregation Funcion to work with this kind of grouping. I'm not fluent at MySQL, but try something pretty much like this, using the group_concat() function:

```
select
    group_concat(b.Name),
    c.Title
from
    A a
    join B b on b.P_id = a.P_id
    join C c on c.G_id = a.G_id
group by
    c.Title
```

Hopefully it'll show you "john,jack"

Check the docs about Aggregation functions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

-- EDIT

Just tested it, it gave me the following output:

```
+----------------------+-------+
| group_concat(b.Name) | Title |
+----------------------+-------+
| john,jack            | php   |
| sam                  | sql   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

I hope is that what you want :)

-- EDIT (the last one)

Now I think I understood what you want, just add `having group_concat(b.Name) like '%john%'` and it'll give you only the groups that `john` is included... The better choice would be an `array contains` function, but I haven't found it.

```
+----------------------+-------+
| group_concat(b.Name) | Title |
+----------------------+-------+
| john,jack            | php   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

Comment: You could probably get better performance with a couple of extra `JOIN`s. Get only the "john" row from table B then `JOIN` to A to get his title(s), then `JOIN` to B again for everyone with the same title(s). Then `JOIN` in A & C for the concatenation and the title name.

Comment: That could be tested, because essentially, more joins = more processing... But I agree that in terms of design, it would be better.